# AngularJS Error: Cannot set property 'UserData' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I run the following AngularJS code from a partial page:

```
$scope.$parent.UserData = {};
$http.get('http://.../GetUserData/').
then(function (result) {
    $scope.$parent.UserData = result.data;
}, function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I know that $scope.$parent is not null and I know that result.data returns an object with multiple properties. Not sure why I am getting this error since $scope.$parent is not null

The above partial page is displayed in `ui-view` on index page. Here is html from index page:

```
<body ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
    <nav>

    </nav>

    <div class="" ui-view>
    //partial pages displayed here
    </div>


 <!-- Modal Structure -->
 <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Heading</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td>{{UserData.ID}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person name:</td>
                    <td>{{UserData.Name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-click="closeModal()" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: you can try logging the $scope object first to check if it has a $parent?

Comment: Can you update your question with console.log?

Comment: if I use console.log($scope.$parent) I get `[object Object]`

Comment: Can you paste the HTML view please, it will be easy to understand the scenario why is $parent empty in your scope

Comment: can you provide plunker link please

Comment: I updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not defined `$scope.$parent`. So define it first.

```
$scope.$parent = {};
$scope.$parent.UserData = {};
$http.get('http://.../GetUserData/').
then(function (result) {
    $scope.$parent.UserData = result.data;
}, function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Optimal syntax for object of objects.

```
$scope.$parent = {UserData:{}};
```

Comment: There should noit be a problem with $scope.$parent since before setting `UserData` I already stored variables in `$scope.$parent.MyValue` without an issue

    `$http.get('http://.../GetValue/').
            
    then(function (result) {
         $scope.$parent.MyValue = result.data;
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
              
  console.log(error);
    });`
  
The code above is executed in the controller for the partial page. This data meant to be displayed in the header on the index page that contains a `ui-view` for displaying partial page:

Answer (score 0):

could please try this

```
$http.get('http://.../GetUserData/').
then(function (result) {
    $scope.$parent.UserData = {};
    $scope.$parent.UserData = result.data;
}, function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Coild you please provide the htmls AND Parent contoller and child controller details

Answer (score 0):

After a while of trying out different things I finally came up with the solution. Here is what worked for me:

```
$scope.$parent.UserDataColl = [];
$http.get('http://.../GetUserData/').
then(function (result) {
    $scope.UserDataColl.push(result.data); 
}, function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```